# Enabling and disabling fields

Tags: javascript

I have a form that has two drop down fields lets say `A` is one and `B` is another. I want the drop down box `B` to be disabled until one of the value in the drop down `A` is selected .

How should I write a Java script?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onchange` event of dropdown A to check it's value and change the `disabled` property of dropdown B:

```
document.getElementById("dropdown_A").onchange = function ()
{
    if (this.selectedIndex == 2) // if the 3rd option is selected
        document.getElementById("dropdown_B").disabled = true;
}
```

Note this code needs to run after the dropdown A element (or the entire document) has been parsed.

Answer (score 0):

For your dropdown_b, make the disabled property = "disabled"
for your dropdown_a, make the onchange to a function that will change dropdown_b's disabled property.

```
<html>
<head>
window.onload = function()
{
   dda = document.getElementById("dropdown_A");
   ddb = document.getElementById("dropdown_b");

   dda.onchange = function()
   {
      if(dda.options[dda.selectedIndex] != "")
         ddb.disabled = "";
   };
}
</head>
<body>
<select id="dropdown_A">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="asdf">asdf</option>
<option value="12345">12345</option>
</select>
<select id="dropdown_B">
..
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, until the user selects an actual option nothing will happen... so the blank option [""] won't deselect the other select.